# Conservation law solution with tricky initial data

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics

For the conservation law

$\partial_tu+u\partial_xu=0$ for $(x,t)\in\mathbb{R}\times[0,T)$

$u(x,0)=\arctan(x)$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}$

I have been asked to find an explicit equation for $u(x,t)$. However I am having trouble doing so. I know that the critical time $T$ for which a classic solution exists is $\infty$ because $\partial_s(\arctan(s))=\frac{1}{1+s^2}>0$ for all $s\in\mathbb{R}$. (For a finite critical time we would need at least one point where $\partial_s(\arctan(s))<0$ which is not true).

So by the method of characteristics for $(X(\tau,s),T(\tau,s),Z(\tau,s))$ I get that $X=\arctan(s)\tau+s$, $T=\tau$, and $Z=\arctan(s)$. From this I know that $Z(X,T)=\frac{X-tan(Z(X,T))}{T}$, and so the implicit equation for $u(x,t)$ is $u(x,t)=\frac{x-tan(u(x,t))}{t}$. I have no idea how to get this into an explicit form for $u(x,t)$, though. (I already suspect that maybe my implicit function is wrong because of the discontinuity of $\tan$ but I'm not sure if that's relevant or not).

Comment: The general solution of the PDE is $u= f(x - ut)$ for some differentiable function $f$. Applying the initial condition gives \begin{align} u(x,0) &= f(x - u(x,0) \cdot 0) \\ &= f(x) \\ &= \arctan(x) \\ \implies u &= \arctan(x - ut) \end{align} which is the same as your solution, so your implicit solution isn't wrong. I just don't think it is possible to isolate $u$ here.

Comment: I agree with the solution on the form of implicit equation $$u=\arctan(x-t\:u)$$ There is no explicit form for $u$ as a function of $x$ and $t$ with a finite number of available standard functions. Equivalently one can explicitly express $x(u,t)$ and $t(u,x)$.

Comment: Thanks both, perhaps the wording of the original problem was incorrect then?